# docker cp does not copy recursively

Tags: docker

I have the following containers:

```
» sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
753f4d01ae32        postgres:9             /usr/src/postgres/do   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        5432/tcp                 postgres            
edfbfb3b0837        tutum/couchdb:latest   /run.sh                18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:5985->5984/tcp   couchdb2            
4aa61e51d86f        tutum/couchdb:latest   /run.sh                18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp   couchdb
```

I am working with the postgres container:

```
CID=753f4d01ae32
PID=$(sudo docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} $CID)
echo $PID
13949
» sudo nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid /bin/bash
root@753f4d01ae32:/# ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/data/
total 100
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres     4 Aug  1 05:30 PG_VERSION
drwx------ 5 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 base
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 global
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 pg_clog
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  4506 Aug  1 05:30 pg_hba.conf
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  1636 Aug  1 05:30 pg_ident.conf
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 pg_multixact
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 pg_notify
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 pg_serial
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 pg_snapshots
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 pg_stat
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:41 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 pg_subtrans
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 pg_tblspc
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 pg_twophase
drwx------ 3 postgres postgres  4096 Aug  1 05:30 pg_xlog
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 20494 Aug  1 05:30 postgresql.conf
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    30 Aug  1 05:30 postmaster.opts
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    70 Aug  1 05:30 postmaster.pid
```

Cool, so I have the data in `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. I want a copy of that data, to check the config in the host and so on:

```
» sudo docker cp $CID:/var/lib/postgresql/data .
» tree data/
data/

0 directories, 0 files
```

So, `docker cp` has not copied anything! Why?

I am using:

```
» docker --version
Docker version 0.9.1, build 3600720
```

Comment: This works for me on 1.1 - upgrade your docker?

Comment: I have the stock docker of ubuntu 14.04. Maybe I'll upgrade manually then. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Old Version cannot `docker cp` data from Volume. Update to 1.4.0 or newer, it works!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it's relevant again for Docker 1.12 - files are copied fine but not into directories already created on volumes on the container.

Created an issue here:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25755